# Using MapInfo to create legend which shows points within named polygon?

Tags: mapinfo, legend

I've created a map which shows some pupil post codes as points on the map and it also contains a layer which shows Wards within the city.

I would like to create a legend or table which shows how many pupils reside in each ward and the councillor responsible for the ward.

Is there a way to do this in MapInfo? I have already created a table in excel which shows this but i need the information to be on the map.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Table` > `Update Column` to update a column in your `Wards` table with the count of the number of pupils within it. To do this fill out your `Update Column` window as below:

Table to Update: `Wards`

Column to Update: `NumPupils` (add this to your table if necessary)

Get Value from Table: `PupilPostcodes`

Click the '`Join`' button and set the radio button to '`where object from table...`' and change the drop-down so that the pupil postcode points are within the Wards (or the Wards contain the pupil postcode points). Click OK to go back to the `Update Column` window.

Calculate: `Count`

Click OK and you should now have a count of the number of pupils against each Ward.

You should then be able to display this in a Legend window (`Map` > `Create Legend`), just use the wizard to create the legend and select the correct column to label the Legend with.